# Does C# allow omitting class parameter inside its methods?

Tags: c#, class

While I was cleaning the code for my project, I stumbled upon a method within the class like following (simplified)

```
public static class HelperClass
{
   public static void DoStuff(this DifferentClassName obj)
}
```

After performing a quick search, aside from definition, the search result gave me the following:

```
varname.DoStuff();
```

Obviously, I thought that it didn't have anything to do with the method in the class, so I commented out the class method so see if it would cause any errors. To my surprise, the line from search result was redded-out.

The snippet of the search result line is as following:

```
var varname = new DifferentClassName()
{
    //stuff inside
}

varname.DoStuff(); //<==what about parameter??
```

I initially thought that it was because a new instance of class created, but shouldn't it still be a parameter inside the line in question? Can anyone please explain why these methods are tied to each other, while the parameter inside the method call was omitted?

Comment: its a special type of method called an extension method.  You can research them, but you can determine it is one in that it is 1) a static method in a static class 2) uses the `this` keyword on its first parameter.

Comment: @TamasHegedus While it did answer my question, I was not aware about the actual method. Is it still going to be marked as duplicate?

Comment: It is as it is going to have the same potential answers, but don't worry about it. You already have an answer here too, and your question still can be upvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Methods with `(this Foo foo)` are *[extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx)*. Extension methods have certain rules that apply (*read link provided*).

When these methods are in proper static classes - e.g. `public` or `internal` - any object that is the subject of the extension method essentially has that method *tacked* on to it's API. The subject object is then assumed as the first parameter.

You can call extension methods in 2 ways:

```
// assuming extension class as follows
public static class Extensions {
    // Foo is the subject Type and foo the subject object
    public static void DoBarWithFoo(this Foo foo){
        // do something with foo
    }
}

var foo = new Foo();

// call ...
foo.DoBarWithFoo();
// or ...
Extensions.DoBarWithFoo(foo);
```

Comment: Then, is it similar to Javascript, where, say, you have function with 5 parameters, and you are calling function with 3 parameters, it only assumes values of first 3 parameters?

Comment: No, it's quite different, check the "extension methods" link that IAbstract provided